# log message xcode: throwing -10878 sinds Version 13.1 (13A1030d)

Tags: swift, xcode

Since the xcode version: 13.1 the following message appears in the log:

**2021-12-05 13:05:56.227305+0100**

**appname[7673:355574] throwing -10878**

and is repeated at least 150 times end ended with the message:

**appname[7673:355574] Writing analzed variants.**

Where 'appname' is the name of the app i am working on:

But I did not create these log messages!

Does anyone know what is causing these log-messages?

Kind regards Arvid

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the `Writing analzed variants` this is official [Apple statement](https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/689066)

Comment: Thx! I'll treat it then see it as log-noise. But it is very annoying!!